# Swift 3 : 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginwritetransaction on an RLMRealm instance first'

Tags: ios, swift, realm

When I try to update object in Realm above error occurs.
I've attached my code.

```
class FHRealm
{
    static let sharedInstance = try! Realm()

    class func writeUserToRealm(userInfo:userInfo)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            autoreleasepool
                {
                    sharedInstance.beginWrite()
                    sharedInstance.add(userInfo)
                    try! sharedInstance.commitWrite()
            }
        }
    }

    class func updateUserInRealm(userInfo:userInfo)
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            autoreleasepool
            {
                    sharedInstance.beginWrite()
                    sharedInstance.add(userInfo, update:true)
                    try! sharedInstance.commitWrite()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I called Update function in my ViewController.

`FHRealm.updateUserInRealm(userInfo: userInfo.sharedInstance)`

I can't expect what's wrong.
Please Help me.

Comment: Try remove dispatch and run again

Comment: I've tried but Same result :(

Comment: Then try move `let sharedInstance = try! Realm()` inside the function, my guess is similar to the answer below but might not be the case

Comment: I write object to Realm in one viewcontroller and after that I update object in Realm from other viewcontroller.

Comment: When I write first, it works.

Comment: But update is not working.

Comment: When I call write and update function separately, they works.

Comment: But when I call them continuously, they don't work.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not see the exact cause of your problem, but this could be a lead:
`sharedInstance` is probably on the main thread. And you are passing realm Object to it, maybe from another thread.

And if you read the [Realm docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#using-a-realm-across-threads):

> The only rule to using Realm across threads is to remember that Realm, RealmObject or RealmResults instances cannot be passed across threads.

So I'd say, for a start, that instead of calling your wrapper, try to do the operation directly from the caller object.